# Issue while running OpenCv Python script on Amazon-Ec2 Instance

Tags: php, python, opencv, amazon-ec2

I am calling a Python script using php System() function.

Python script implements the Foreground subtraction using OpenCv library. I upload the image using Post request and then pass the file to the script.

Following things are getting executed in the code

```
1. Uploading file through Post request.
2. Passing the file to Python Script
3. Script reads the file, implements the 
   Foreground subtraction algorithm    
   and saves this to a new file.
```

I am Testing this program using two images, 1500 * 701 pixels and 2368 * 4208 pixels.

Everything is working fine for the low resolution image. But for the high resolution image, Python script keeps exiting.

Php code.

```
system("python /var/www/html/wowflux/public/scripts/test.py",$ret_val);
var_dump($ret_val);
```

Python script

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import os 
import sys
from sys import path
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

##test_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
test_image = cv2.imread("/var/www/html/wowflux/public/test.jpg")
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
height, width, channels = test_image.shape

h = int(height*0.8)
w = int(width*0.8)
x = int((width-w)/2)
y = int((height-h)/2)
mask = np.zeros((height,width),dtype='uint8')
rect = (x,y,w,h)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
##tmp1 = np.zeros((1, 13 * 5))
##tmp2 = np.zeros((1, 13 * 5))
cv2.grabCut(test_image,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,2,mode=cv2.
GC_INIT_WITH_REC  T)\

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
test_image = test_image*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

cv2.imwrite("/var/www/html/wowflux/public/test1.jpg",test_image)
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
time = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
print time
```

For testing purposes, I have already saved the file and just testing the python script. I am facing the same problem here as well.

On my local host, Program is working fine for both the images. I am facing problem on the Amazon-EC2 instance and that too for the high resolution image.
For the high resolution image, if I comment out the code for Foreground subtraction, time is getting printed. So, It is safe to assume that the problem is with running the Foreground subtraction for high resolution image.